# Vue.js: Child component omits the `ref` attribute

Tags: vue.js, inheritance, attributes

I have created a component called `Input`. All the attributes that are passed to this `Input` component are inherited successfully, but the `ref` attribute is always omitted for some reason.

I need the `ref` attribute to set focus on the element, after the validation fails.

Some.vue

```js
<template>
    ...

    <Input
        type="number"
        name="mobile"
        ref="mobileRef"
        v-model="this.form.mobile"
        :class="errors.mobile ? 'error' : null"
        :error="errors.mobile ?? null"
    />

    ...
</template>

<script>
import Input from '@Inputs/Input';

export default {
    ...

    components: {
        Input,
    },

    ...
}
</script>
```

Input.vue

```js
<template>
    <input
        autocomplete="none"
        class="form-control"
        :ref="ref"
        :class="this.class"
        :type="this.type ?? 'text'"
        :value="modelValue"
        :disabled="disabled"
        @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)"
     />
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'Input',
    inheritAttrs: false,
    props: ['type', 'class', 'error', 'modelValue', 'disabled', 'ref']
}
</script>
```

I even hardcoded the ref attribute with some static value, but the result is same, omitted?
**What am I doing wrong here..?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ref` is a [special attribute](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html), it's not supposed to work as a prop.

It's possible to access root element of a component as `$refs.mobileRef.$el.focus()`. The component can also expose all public methods explicitly, so they would be used as `$refs.mobileRef.focus()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `ref` prop in your `Input.vue` component and add a watcher inside, to watch for some errors. If there is, trigger a `.focus()` on your input element.

*Some.vue*

```js
<template>
    ...

    <Input
        type="number"
        name="mobile"
        v-model="this.form.mobile"
        :class="errors.mobile ? 'error' : null"
        :error="errors.mobile ?? null"
    />

    ...
</template>

<script>
import Input from '@Inputs/Input';

export default {
    ...

    components: {
        Input,
    },

    ...
}
</script>
```

*Input.vue*

```js
<template>
    <input
        autocomplete="none"
        class="form-control"
        ref="mobileRef"
        :class="this.class"
        :type="this.type ?? 'text'"
        :value="modelValue"
        :disabled="disabled"
        @input="$emit('update:modelValue', $event.target.value)"
     />
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'Input',
    inheritAttrs: false,
    props: ['type', 'class', 'error', 'modelValue', 'disabled'],
    watch: {
      error(val) {
        if (val)
          this.$refs.mobileRef.focus();
      },
    },
}
</script>
```

Comment: the suggested is working. But in case of multiple uses of the `Input` component it will not work. For example, a form has multiple input fields and hardcoding the ref will generate issues